# C struct with array size determined at compile time

Tags: c, struct

How does one build a struct with an array that can be set differently for each struct, ideally by a parameter? The application being a single data type that supports arrays of different, but fixed lengths

My attempt looks somehting like this, which obviously didnt compile:

```
struct Data_struct(n)
{
    int xData[n];
    int test;
};
```

Comment: Err, this `int[n] xData;` wouldn't compile any ways.

Comment: @alk Yeah i realized that pretty quickly. In my defense, it was 5pm on a Friday :P

Answer (score 3):

The only method available is to use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

```
struct Data_struct {
    int test;
    int xData[];
};
```

You would then allocate space for this using `malloc()`:

```
int n = 4;
struct Data_struct *s = malloc(sizeof(struct Data_struct) + n * sizeof(int));
```

Note that we had to explicitly allocate additional space for the flexible array.

Comment: Flexible array members have incomplete type, and so the sizeof operator may not be applied. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: Also please note, that the "array" has to be the last member of the structure, which leads to the implicit constrain that only one such "array"s per `struct` is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically allocate the array

```
struct Data_struct
{
    int * xData;
    int test;
};

....

s.xData = calloc(size, sizeof(int))
```

and remember to free xData when finished

Comment: I'm not sure why this attracted a down-vote - it's certainly a valid answer ?

Comment: Not my downvote, but with your solution the `Data_Struct` is no more a single piece of contiguous memory.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: true, but I don't think there's a single perfect solution - it depends on various factors, so this might be a better solution in some cases (e.g. if you want an array of such structs).

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would define a variable length array at the end of the struct, and then fix up the size at run-time, e.g.

```
typedef struct
{
    int test;
    int xData[1];
} Data_struct;
```

To allocate a struct such as this with a size of `n` for `xData` you'd do soemthing like this:

```
Data_struct * s = malloc(sizeof(Data_struct) + (n - 1) * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: thing to remember here is that you are fooling the compiler. sizeof(DataStruct) will be wrong, passing it by value will fail.

Comment: @pm100: yes, that's true - I don't know if C99's flexible array member (see Bill's answer) is any improvement in this regard ?

Comment: "Struct hack" has been formalized to flexible array member in C99. I would consider this approach deprecated.

Comment: @user3528438: yes, I went for an old skool C89 solution, but Bill's C99 solution is probably preferable in most cases, unless you're stuck with an old compiler without C99 support (still the case for some embedded tool chains !).

Comment: Don't you want an array with zero elements? Then you don't need (n-1), just n in your calloc.

Comment: @RobertJacobs: yes, probably - I've just got a nagging doubt that some compilers may not accept a zero size (could be a gcc extension, or maybe it's just a C++ restriction ?) ? So I played it safe, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One might call this ugly but here goes. Use a #define

```
#define foo(n) struct Data_struct##n { int test; int xData[n]; }

foo(20);

struct Data_struct20 abc;
```

The foo(20) defines a structure with n = 20 characters.
You could use another #define for the allocation of space if you wish.

Comment: OP specifically asks for a "a **single data type** that supports arrays of different, but fixed lengths".

Comment: @PaulR. But you already wrote that answer. Mine doesn't require a malloc which may be useful.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't answer the OP's question as posed, since he wants a single data type - your answer might therefore cause confusion for someone else coming along and reading this question later. So I have to down-vote, regrettably.